# For positive $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, if $\sum_{cyc}\frac1{1+a}=2$, (dis)prove $\frac{4(3\sqrt2-4)}{a+b+c+d}+\sum_{cyc}\frac1{\sqrt a}\geq3\sqrt2$

Tags: inequality, open-problem

An open problem from Art of Problem Solving (AoPS):

> If $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers such that
> $$\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac 1{1+b}+\frac 1{1+c}+\frac 1{1+d}=2,$$then prove or disprove
> $$\frac1{\sqrt a}+\frac1{\sqrt b}+\frac1{\sqrt c}+\frac1{\sqrt d}+\frac{4\left(3\sqrt2-4\right)}{a+b+c+d}\geq3\sqrt2$$

(V. Cîrtoaje and L. Giugiuc, 2022) Link to AoPS and some progress to the problem: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u399206h2794888p24621900

Some Progress

by dragonheart6
Some thoughts (the method of Lagrange Multiplier):

At minimum, $(a, b, c, d)$ satisfies
$$F(a) = F(b) = F(c) = F(d) > 0 \qquad (1)$$where
$$F(u) := \frac{\lambda}{(1 + u)^2} - \frac{1}{2u^{3/2}}.$$($\lambda$ is the Lagrange Multiplier.)
According to (1), try to prove that $|\{a, b, c, d\}| \le 2$ where $|\cdot|$ is the cardinality of a set.

Comment: is there any approach or something that can help solve this problem?

Comment: Actually, just prove that for any positive real number $q$, the equation $F(u) = q$ has at most two positive real solutions, by studying $F(u)$. But I don't like the method of LM, so I don't post it.

Comment: is there any other method that u know to solve this? @RiverLi

Comment: I don't yet find another method.

Comment: if you're done using Lagrange feel free to post it

Comment: for everyone who wanna repost this on different sites like Facebook, Twitter or others just post it don't forget to write or screenshot the problem proposer also (Prof Vasile And Prof Leo Giuc)

Comment: @GregoriusWillson Perhaps you can use (if true I haven't check completely) for $a,x>0$ : $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\geq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{a+x}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{1}{a^{\frac{3}{2}}}}}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{a}{a^{\frac{3}{2}}}}}$$

Comment: @ErikSatie. I do not know what I could do with it but it is a very nice inequality (checked)

Comment: It works with Lagrange multipliers but it is a nightmare

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Why don't use symmetry ?

Comment: @ErikSatie. If you use it, the problem is solved without pen and/or paper

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici if u want to answer with Lagrange i have a post that involve Lagrange https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409059/asking-about-best-upper-bound-and-lowerbound